# jquery cycle2: how to get a slide by its slide number

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle, jquery-cycle2

I am using cycle 2 ( http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/ ) to create a carousel, and I am having trouble figuring out how to access slides by there "slide number".

I can loop through the slide array using cycle.API and find the slide numbers

```
$('#respo-slider').on('cycle-post-initialize', function(e, opts) {
    for(var i=0; i < opts.slideCount; i++){
       var slide_opt = $('#respo-slider').data('cycle.API').getSlideOpts(i);
   var slide_num = slide_opt["slideNum"];
   }
});
```

but I can't find anywhere in the api how to get the element by its slide using jquery (so I can then edit the attributes of the slide element).

What I am looking for is something along the lines of:

```
$('#respo-slider').getSlide(slide_num);
```

I have spent far to long trying to figure this out and I am stumped. Can anyone out there enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

**So like...**

```
$('#respo-slider').children('div').index(slide_num);
```

Assuming the slides are in `div` elements.

The slides are already in order, and their index should be the same as the slide number.

Once the carousel initializes, it's going to duplicate the slides a bunch of times, so you want make your changes before it initializes, not after; since that would give you multiples of each slide.

By making the changes before initialization, the changes should be cloned when the carousel effect is created.